# Manage Permissions in powerbi report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I would like to remove the access of a list of [image] but it seems to me removing them from `RLS.xlsx` file is not working.

how to remove workspace (admin) member from the reports and workspaces ?
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is RLS.xlsx? Workspaces permissions are managed on the Power BI service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-roles-new-workspaces